# Vault hashicorp, access from posgres deployment kubernetes authentication connection refused

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, hashicorp-vault

I would like to add a vault to my kubernetes to store JWT, database passwords etc...

I'm using vault from Hashicorp and I followed this documentation: https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/tutorials/kubernetes/kubernetes-secret-store-driver

My Secret Provider Class and mu ServiceAccount look like :

```yaml
kind: ServiceAccount
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: application-sa
  namespace: application-dev
---
apiVersion: secrets-store.csi.x-k8s.io/v1
kind: SecretProviderClass
metadata:
  name: application-vault-database
  namespace: application-dev
spec:
  provider: vault
  secretObjects:
    - data:
        - key: password
          objectName: db-password
      secretName: dbpass
      type: Opaque
  parameters:
    vaultAddress: "https://127.0.0.1:8200"
    roleName: "database"
    objects: |
      - objectName: "db-password"
        secretPath: "secret/data/db-pass"
        secretKey: "password"
```

and my postgresql database deployment looks like:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: application-postgresql-pvc
  namespace: application-dev
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 2Gi
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: application-postgresql
  namespace: application-dev
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: application-postgresql
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: application-postgresql
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: application-sa
      volumes:
        - name: data
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: application-postgresql-pvc
        - name: secrets-store-inline
          csi:
            driver: secrets-store.csi.k8s.io
            readOnly: true
            volumeAttributes:
              secretProviderClass: "application-vault-database"
      containers:
        - name: postgres
          image: postgres:14.5
          env:
            - name: POSTGRES_USER
              value: application
            - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: dbpass
                  key: password
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
          volumeMounts:
            - name: secrets-store-inline
              mountPath: "/mnt/secrets-store"
              readOnly: true
            - name: data
              mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
              subPath: postgres
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: '512Mi'
              cpu: '500m'
            limits:
              memory: '1Gi'
              cpu: '1'
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: application-postgresql
  namespace: application-dev
spec:
  selector:
    app: application-postgresql
  ports:
    - port: 5432
```

But I'm getting the following error when I start my database pod:

```
MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "secrets-store-inline" : rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to mount secrets store objects for pod application-dev/application-postgresql-7db74cf6b-8b2q4, err: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = error making mount request: couldn't read secret "db-password": failed to login: Post "https://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/auth/kubernetes/login": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8200: connect: connection refused
```

**What I tried: **

regarding my kubernetes config I have :

`kubectl config view``

```bash
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: DATA+OMITTED
    server: https://xxx.api.k8s.fr-par.scw.cloud:6443
  name: k8s-application
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: k8s-application
    user: k8s-application-admin
  name: admin@k8s-application
current-context: admin@k8s-application
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: k8s-application-admin
  user:
    token: REDACTED
```

the server is: https://xxx.api.k8s.fr-par.scw.cloud:6443

So I assumed that I had to change my vault kubernetes config to :

```bash
vault write auth/kubernetes/config \
>     kubernetes_host="https://xxx.api.k8s.fr-par.scw.cloud:6443"
```

instead of `$KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_ADDR`

For info `$KUBERNETES_PORT_443_TCP_ADDR` is `10.32.0.1`

I also tried to the `vaultAddress` in the SPC to "http://vault.default:8200" like in the documentation

Then I got Post "http://vault.default:8200/v1/auth/kubernetes/login": dial tcp: lookup vault.default on 10.32.0.10:53: no such host

So i guess connection refused of the original conf mean that the host "https://127.0.0.1:8200" is correct but that something is wrong with the kubernetes auth?

What do you think?

Regards

Comment: It seems unlikely that your vault address is `https://127.0.0.1:8200`. `127.0.0.1` is the loopback address and almost never makes sense in a connection string.

Comment: any suggestion how can I get my vault address @larsks ?

Comment: Where is your vault running? Is it a service on the same Kubernetes cluster, or is it running somewhere else? If it's running on the kubernetes cluser, there should be a Service resource associated with it; your vault hostname is `<servicename>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local` (often shortended to simply `<servicename>.<namespace>`); see "[DNS for Services and Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/)" for more information).

Comment: E.g., in [the documentation to which you linked](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/tutorials/kubernetes/kubernetes-secret-store-driver#define-a-secretproviderclass-resource), they've deployed vault into the `default` namespace so that vault address is `http://vault.default:8200`.

Comment: I deployed in application-dev: so the address should be `http://vault.application-dev:8200 ` ?

Comment: got :  failed to login: Post "http://vault.application-dev:8200/v1/auth/kubernetes/login": dial tcp: lookup vault.application-dev on 10.32.0.10:53: no such host

Comment: There's really not enough information in your question for us to figure out what's going on. It sounds like you're not following the linked tutorial exactly, so you may want to start with that and see if things work as expected.

Comment: Your vault address is not proper, try doing "kubectl get service -n namespace" and check the vault service name and its port and then try the same thing if it is in the same cluster

http://vault-service-name.namespace:port

if it is not in same cluster then try running "kubectl get ingress -n namespace" in the cluster where vault is deployed

and use the ingress url in vault address and make sure the vault url should be reachable from your application pod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to @Srishti Khandelwal

I needed to kubectl get service -n namespace

and use the name in my config :

`http://vault-service-name.namespace:port`

Comment: Glad it worked for you 